# how to force the evaluation of this expression?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

```
module Main where

import Control.Parallel(par,pseq)
import Text.Printf
import Control.Exception
import System.CPUTime
import Data.List
import IO
import Data.Char
import Control.DeepSeq

time :: IO t -> IO t
time a = do
   start <- getCPUTime
   v <- a
   end <- getCPUTime
   let diff = (fromIntegral (end - start)) / (10^12)
   printf "Computation time: %0.3f sec\n" (diff :: Double)
   return v

learquivo :: FilePath -> IO ([[Int]])
learquivo s = do
   content <- readFile s
   return (read content)

main :: IO ()
main = do
   t5 <- getCPUTime
   content <- learquivo "mkList1.txt"
   let !mapasort = rnf $ map sort content
   t6 <- getCPUTime
   let diffft6t5 = (fromIntegral (t6 - t5)) / (10^12)
   printf "Computation time Mapasort: %0.3f sec\n" (diffft6t5 :: Double)
```

How to tell if it evaluates all elements of content?

```
let !mapasort = rnf $ map sort content
```

I used the line in winghci:

```
*Main> let !mapasort = rnf $ map sort content
```

But, returned:

```
*Main> mapasort ()
```

Thanks

Comment: Note I fixed your posted code so it actually runs.  Please verify it reflects the code you ran.

Comment: There is a package available on hackage for timing IO. It's called System.TimeIt, and works in the same way as the time function you have given

Comment: Thanks, Jonno_FTW, I'll replace in my program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two questions:

*1) Why is mapsort evaluating to unit, `()`.*

Because the `rnf` function always returns `()`.  [See the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/deepseq/1.1.0.1/doc/html/Control-DeepSeq.html).

*2) Is everything evaluated*

Yes.  The DeepSeq instance (which is where `rnf` lives) for list just calls the deepseq instance for each element in the list:

```
rnf [] = ()
rnf (x:xs) = rnf x `seq` rnf xs
```

Your elements all Ints, which have a correct NFData instance.

And I'd add two more questions:

*3) How should this benchmarking be done correctly?*

Using [Criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion).  There are many Criterion advocates here on SO, you can find answers that would serve as good examples with a search.

*4) How should this evaluation be forced for non-benchmarking purposes?*

Using the parallel package.

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
...
let !mapsort = (map sort content) `using` (evalList rdeepseq)
```

or still using `rnf`:

```
let mapsort = map sort content
    !_ = rnf mapsort
```

Comment: Ok, TomMD, I managed to install Criterion, but I could not use, so kept insisting on doing so, but so am getting a very short runtime, so I thought there was something wrong. I'll try using Criterion, and put the questions here because I looked at the documentation, I tried to do something but did not work.
Thanks.

Comment: try this:
cabal install -f-Chart criterion
that way you can avoid all the gtk stuff that sometimes gives trouble.